# How does an OS run before drivers are installed?

Tags: linux, windows, drivers, bsd

I am looking into hardware compatibility of BSD vs Linux vs Windows. One comment that keeps reoccurring is "check your hardware before installing any variant of BSD". This is also a (smaller) issue for Linux, but does not appear to be a problem at all for Windows because Windows will happily run on any hardware.

I understand that hardware vendors will primarily write device drivers for Windows because Windows has the vast majority of OS market share. This is fine, except that I can run a fresh install of Windows without having installed any device drives at all, and the OS will still run (and once it does, I then install the drivers). My question is therefore:

- How can an OS (Windows, in this case) boot and run without the installation of any device drivers, and
- Why can't Linux and BSD do the same thing?

Comment: Windows has generic drivers for the devices that it needs to provide basic functionality. Linux and BSD can and often do the same.

Comment: As a note, Windows doesn't always work on all hardware; I've had particular problems with certain network cards. The drivers exist, but they aren't available through Microsoft. Some hardware RAID can also cause problems.

Comment: Try running some older hardware on 64-bit versions of Windows and watch what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux and BSD have kernel support for an incredible range of hardware right out the gate. The big difference is if a hardware manufacturer creates a main board that uses new chipsets that Linux/BSD developers don’t have access to right away, then support will be limited. In general Windows developers will be seeded new hardware as part of the standard Windows certification program. Not so much with Linux developers.

But all this usually means is support for some features won’t immediately appear in a Linux install if you are using bleeding edge hardware. Given time, new hardware gets supported and adopted with ease by the Linux/BSD world.

The only caveat: From my experience Linux/BSD support of hardware is based on server needs. Meaning graphic drivers lag behind, but the rest of the core system is solid. It’s because Linux/BSD is readily adopted by the server world more-so than the desktop world. Ditto with non-standard mouse functions. Generally you can just plug in any mouse into a Linux/BSD setup and it will work as a basic mouse. But if it is multi-button or has non-standard features, chances are high those features will not work unless drivers are written explicitly for them.

One place that this stuff does get seriously snagged is manufacturer closed source onboard RAID setups such as those from HP. In cases like that, it’s best to just get a supported RAID card add-on and not worry about the “bonus” of onboard RAID for a server that would usually only be able to handle RAID 0 or RAID 1 anyway. Those RAID setups are not anything to write home about from an enterprise server environment perspective  and an add-on card is a better bet for long term support from the vendor and the Linux community as well.

Answer (score 1):

Modern Windows versions (e.g. Win 7 and newer) can boot and run (as in, reach the Windows Desktop without crashing) because Microsoft included drivers for the most common hardware in the installation disc, and they were installed when Windows was installed. These included drivers get you to the desktop and Internet access, so you can get things done.

This is also true for many modern Linux distributions (so yes, they *can* do the same thing -- get you to desktop and Internet right out of box). However, for both Windows and other OS alike, not *all* hardware functions will work, especially for new and uncommon hardware, until you install the manufacturer-provided drivers from CD or Internet.